# Java: Interview questions for software tester?

Tags: java, testing

These days I have an interview for the position:  Software Testing Engineer.

Any ideas what questions might pop to the interview? Any tips?

Comment: I know what might pop, but maybe there some questions which are asked very often.

Comment: *"Let's play word association, I'll start: Java"* "Starbucks!" *"I'll show you the door."* ":<"

Answer (score 7):

You should be more specific in your question.

If the keyword here is **Java** Software Tester, than expect questions about:
 unit testing (assertions, test suits, testSetUp etc), unit testing frameworks (junit, testNG), mocks usage and different mock frameworks(EasyMock, Mockito, jMock), Continuous Integration, Test Driven Development, Behavior Driven Development, working with code repository,code coverage, path coverage, statement coverage, tools for bug tracking (bugzilla/jira)...  maybe some about class invariants, design by contract...
You can get something practical like, code review, write tests for some class/interface, write something using TDD approach.

If the keywords are Java **Software Tester** than expect questions about:
 Boundary Values, Equivalence Classes, black-box testing, white-box testing, Test Case, Test Suite, Bug Report, Software Development models (V model, waterfall, DSDM, iterative, agile approach), role of testing in development cycle, role of a tester on development team, when testing is enough, what is quality, definitions and differences between issue, bug, defect, fault, what differences in iseb/istqb/Tmap certifications, what is difference between System/Integration/UserAcceptance/smoke/regression testing, when to automatize and what are pros and cons, tools for test acclimatization (not unit tests), tools for test/bug management (HP QualityCenter/IBM Rational Quality Manager)...
As for practical stuff: how would you test installer or wizard, write bug report, re-design/optimize test case/script, (if position connected with test acclimatization) write code snippet in VBscript (or other scripting language).

In either case check SO for questions with proper tags and/or google for mentioned topics.

Answer (score 6):

**What is software testing ?**

Answer (score 3):

How do you go about testing software?

Here's a link I found with a list of interview questions you might be interested in:
http://www.buzzle.com/articles/software-testing-interview-questions.html

Answer (score 2):

I like this one: what is the difference between verification and validation?

Comment: I personally don't like that one. People often use them idistinctly and doesn't really tell much about what the person really know about test management or execution. In the other hand, it will certanly tell you is the candidate has ever taken a course or has studied for a certification exam.

Comment: its like the difference between authorization and authentication?

Answer (score 1):

a Java-specific question for a tester would be (targeting the awareness of Exceptions)

- what do you look for when there is a problem with the software you are testing?

Answer (score 0):

What part does testing takes in software development cycle? (You start writing tests the day you start project and put some of your best engineers to do that. When the project is almost done you test it)

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the software business the behavior and openness of people is very important. That's especially true for testing people.

I would try to know if the person is going to be able to work with the dev team and ask him what he is doing when he is testing software with a lot of very obvious bugs. How does it work with the developer to improve that situation?
I think that he should find a way to help the developer for example by proposing to make smoke-tests and to integrate it into the build process or by reviewing the unit tests.

I would also ask the person to write a defect report and see if it is clear enough for the one in charge of fixing it.

Joel's test mentions that you must ask a developer to write code during his interview. In the same way, I think that you must ask a tester to write a defect report.

The tester should also be able to write automation tests for API testing. Although this is a specific requirement.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the link below and you will get a idea of the questions asked in the interview.

http://www.geekinterview.com/Interview-Questions/Testing

http://www.testinginterviewquestions.com/

Answer (score 0):

Software Testing is not language dependent. A quick search on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=Software+Testing+Interview&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) gave me what you are looking for